# Make C++ function (or variable) available to R and Rcpp functions

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I would like to use this function (or just the String it returns):

```
const char* ERROR_TYPE() {
  return "unknown type detected for big.matrix object!";
}
```

in my R(cpp) package.

I want to make it available to all my Rcpp functions (files in src/) and to all my tests (R files in tests/testthat/) .

In other terms, I would like to use `throw Rcpp::exception(MESSAGE);` and `testthat::expect_error(foo(), MESSAGE)` where MESSAGE is defined *once*.

I tried to read and test some of what is said in [Rcpp Attributes](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-attributes.pdf) but it doesn't seem to work for my problem.

---

The first thing I've tried is to define

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
const char* ERROR_TYPE() {
  return "unknown type detected for big.matrix object!";
}
```

but it doesn't scope to other Rcpp files.
Then, I tried to `#include "myfile.cpp"` in others Rcpp files but I had multiple defines, even when trying to use `inline` or `#ifndef #define #endif` but I think it's odd for an C++ file.
Finally, I tried to use a `inst/include/mypackage.h` and define my function or my variable there but it didn't seem to scope to other C++ functions as well.

One trick seems to work, define an R function

```
ERROR_TYPE <- function() {
  "unknown type detected for big.matrix object!"
}
```

and then use

```
Function err("ERROR_TYPE");
throw Rcpp::exception(as<const char*>(err()));
```

in your Rcpp functions.
Doesn't seem to be good practice though.
And, it works with `devtools::test()` but not `devtools::check()` or Travis-CI (can't find the function) so it is not a solution as well.

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far? Have you looked at the [RcppExamples](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppExamples/index.html) package and its source code on GitHub?

Comment: I've edited my post, adds below the line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use function defined in one cpp file in function defined in another cpp file in Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44892388/use-function-defined-in-one-cpp-file-in-function-defined-in-another-cpp-file-in)

Comment: Nop, I want a string (error message) to be available to my Rcpp functions **AND my R functions (especially my tests)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `inst/include/utils.h`:

  ```
  #ifndef UTILS_H
  #define UTILS_H   

  const char* const ERROR_TYPE = "unknown type detected for big.matrix object!";

  #endif // UTILS_H
  ```
- Include this header in all Rcpp files that need it
- Make an Rcpp function that return this error message:

  ```
  #include <bigstatsr/utils.h>

  // [[Rcpp::export]]
  const char* const GET_ERROR_TYPE() {
    return ERROR_TYPE;
  }
  ```
- Use `GET_ERROR_TYPE()` in your R functions