# Use function defined in one cpp file in function defined in another cpp file in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I have a c++ function called `add` defined in file *add.cpp* (content of *add.cpp* below):

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double add(double a, double b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

I have another c++ function called `multiplyandadd` defined in *multiplyandadd.cpp* file (content of *multiplyandadd.cpp* below) that calls `add` function from above:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double multiplyandadd(double a, double b, double c) {
  return c*add(a, b);
}
```

In order for this to work I figured out I should create a header file *add.h* in sub folder */inst/include* of my package and define function `add` in *add.h*...

What should the content of *add.h* be? How to define this function `add` in *add.h* so that the package compiles?

I am sure this is very basic and probably answered many times before and very well documented with tons of examples... It just happens I was not able to find an example in a couple of hours reading docs, stackoverflow answers, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with headers, you need to use an [inclusion guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). Within the inclusion guard, provide the appropriate function definition. If your function has default parameters, include the default parameters **only** in the header file.

For example:

**inst/include/add.h**

```
#ifndef PACKAGENAME_ADD_H
#define PACKAGENAME_ADD_H

double add(double a = 0.1, double b = 0.2);

#endif
```

**src/add.cpp**

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <add.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double add(double a, double b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

**src/multiplyandadd.cpp**

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <add.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double multiplyandadd(double a, double b, double c) {
  return c*add(a, b);
}
```

**src/Makevars**

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS =  -I../inst/include/
```

Comment: Could this be used to use `add` in another package?

Answer (score 0):

OK. Figured it out... :)

add.h:

```
//add.h

#ifndef __ADD_H_INCLUDED__   // if add.h hasn't been included yet...
#define __ADD_H_INCLUDED__   //   #define this so the compiler knows it has been included

double add(double a, double b);

#endif
```

And, I need Makevars in src with content:

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS = -I../inst/include
```

I understand it is the most basic thing. Having such a basic example somewhere would make things easier for people first time using Rcpp.

Comment: The header defines using  __ are not valid in C++ identifiers. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier/228797#228797 (These are generally reserved for the compiler.) Outside of that... Not bad!